# Opening Developer tools stops PHP refresh?

Tags: php, refresh, developer-tools

I made a page such that it will reload for every 10 seconds with new information from database. Now the problem is if I open developer tools, it does not reload, it simply pauses. Is there a way to prevent that?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["start"]))
{   
    ++$_SESSION["count"];
    if($_SESSION["count"]==21)
        header("Location:finish.php");
    if($_SESSION["count"]==20)
        header("Refresh:10,url=finish.php");
    $qID=$_SESSION["count"];
    retrieveQstn($qID);

    if($_SESSION["count"]<20)
        header("Refresh:10");


    if($_SESSION["count"]>21)
        {   $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();
        }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["start"]=1;
    $_SESSION["count"]=1;

    header("Refresh:3");
    $qID=$_SESSION["count"];

    retrieveQstn(1);
}

if(isset($_POST["ans"]))
{
    $val = $_POST["ans"];
    $preQstNo = $_SESSION["prevQstnNo"];
    $Qno = $_SESSION["count"] - 1;
    $my_sqlcon = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "","zs14");
    $query = "INSERT INTO quizdata(Q1,A1)VALUES('$preQstNo', '$val')";

}

function retrieveQstn($qID){
    $qstnNo = mt_rand(((($qID-1)*30)+1),$qID*30);
    $_SESSION["qstnNo"] = $qstnNo;
    $_SESSION["prevQstnNo"] = $qstnNo;
    $my_sqlcon = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "","zs14");
    $query = "SELECT question FROM quiz WHERE Q_ID=$qstnNo";
    if(!($retrieve = $my_sqlcon->query($query)))
        echo "Error - Question Retrieval";
    $row = $retrieve->fetch_row();
    $qstn = $row[0];
    echo "<h2>".$qID.".".$qstn."</h2>";
}
function showOptions($no)
{
    $qstnNo = $_SESSION["qstnNo"];
    $my_sqlcon = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "","zs14");
    $query = "SELECT Op$no FROM quiz WHERE Q_ID=$qstnNo";
    if(!($retrieve = $my_sqlcon->query($query)))
        echo "Error - Question Retrieval";
    $row = $retrieve->fetch_row();
    $option = $row[0];
    echo $option;
}
echo '<script>function start(){ id=50;setInterval(function(){id--;document.getElementById("timerp").innerHTML="<h2>" + id + "</h2>";},1000);}</script>'
?>
<body onload="start()" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<span id="timerp"></span>
<form style="position:absolute; top:280px; left:50px;"action= "<?php echo       htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="quiz" method="post">
<input name="ans" type="radio" value="a">
<?php showOptions(1);?></br>
<input name="ans" type="radio" value="b">
<?php showOptions(2);?></br>
<input name="ans" type="radio" value="c">
<?php showOptions(3);?></br>
<input name="ans" type="radio" value="d">
<?php showOptions(4);?></br>
<input name="ans" type="radio" value="e">blank
</form>
</body> 
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {input[i].onclick = function(){form.submit();}}
}
</script>
</html>
```

The code here refreshes page for 20 times for every 10 seconds. For 20th time after refreshing, it moves to next page finish.php. retrieveQstn(), for every page refresh gets a new question randomly from the database and displays. showOptions() displays the corresponding options for the question showed. The JavaScript inside PHP displays a timer for 10 seconds(It does not refresh the page). The JavaScript inside HTML tag submits the form(refreshes page) as soon as the user clicks the radio button. 
The latter Javascript refreshes page only if user clicks radio button. PHP refreshes page for every 10 seconds irrespective of whether the user had selected an option or not.

Now if I place a breakpoint on either of the Javascript, it pauses and not refresh within 10 seconds.

Comment: Do you mean your using AJAX? If so are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Please share the code you're using to make the page reload. Im pretty sure it's not via PHP :)